# Regex issues in Unix when value assigned to a variable

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

Having a problem while redirecting output to variable in Unix.

mobileTest.txt

```
abc.xyx.homepage:https://www.abc.xyz/h-offer/?fromms=1&LNX=KJHYU&oC=ABC
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_PAGE_KEY="abc.xyx.homepage"

grep -w $TEST_PAGE_KEY  mobileTest.txt | cut -d':'  -f2-|sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g'
```

Output: This is correct...

```
https:\/\/www.abc.xyz\/h-offer\/?fromms=1\&LNX=KJHYU\&oC=ABC
```

By contrast, when capturing the command's output in a variable:

```
TEST_PAGE_VALUE=`grep -w $TEST_PAGE_KEY  mobileTest.txt | cut -d':'  -f2-|sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g'`

echo $TEST_PAGE_VALUE
```

Output from variable:

```
https:&&www.abc.xyz&h-offer&?fromms=1&LNX=KJHYU&oC=ABC
```

I don't understand why the output is different (instead of adding a backslash, it replaces the character with `&`) when I assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit upon one of the reasons [why the modern `$(...)` command-substitution syntax is preferable to legacy syntax `` `...` ``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082):

With `$(...)`, you needn't worry about `\` chars. in your command having special meaning in the context of the command substitution.

Thus, **using `$(...)` rather than `` `...` `` will yield the desired result**:

```
test_page_value=$(grep -w "$TEST_PAGE_KEY"  mobileTest.txt | cut -d':'  -f2-|sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g')
```

<sup>Also note how I've avoided an all-uppercase variable name in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01), and how I've double-quoted (still poorly named) `$TEST_PAGE_KEY` in order to protect it from potential shell expansions.</sup>